# Should I use one index or multiple ones in Algolia?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algolia

I'm building a product search widget that e-commerce clients integrate into their website. Let's say I have 100 clients with 1000 products each.

Visitors on a particular client's website are only able to search for that client's products.

Given that products share the exact same attributes (id, name, price, etc...) across clients:

**Should I use a separate index for each client, or one index to store all clients' products and somehow associate each product with a client?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you to create a separate index for each client, since it allows you to have

- different index configuration if needed (typo-tolerance, synonyms)
- separated analytics
- the possibility of creating a different a API key
  each index (see doc)

Which is not the case if you go with the other approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one index only. Use a `before_action :find_client` method where your client is find by a param such as client_id

So in the private section of your controller add

```
private 
def find_client
 @client = Client.find(params[:client_id]) 
end
```

and make sure that the user can only see the products of this client. For this to work you need to pass a client_id in the params when accessing the index page.

Than, depending on your app's structure in your index action you need to filter the products for the client. Where the client is set by your find_client method.